# visual studio code error ) expected css-rparentexpected version 1.62.2?

Tags: visual-studio-code

after updating VSC to version 1.62.2 there was a problem, swears at this syntax

```
 @media screen and (max-width: $tablet - 1px) {
    margin-bottom: vw($mobile, 35px);
  }
```

$ tablet contains 830 digits.
The problem is the minus! Swears at him.
Before everything was ok! There are many such lines in the project.

in the terminal console on the problems tab, the list with these errors ") expected" The detailed text of each error is approximately the same:

```
[{
    "resource": "",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "css-rparentexpected",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": ") expected",
    "source": "scss",
    "startLineNumber": 278,
    "startColumn": 43,
    "endLineNumber": 278,
    "endColumn": 44
}]
```

Please tell me how to cure this in the new version of the VSC?
It is desirable on the software side, it is not desirable to edit the SCSS code in the project, there are a lot of lines, and everything works and worked always, only the highlighting in red and the presence of errors in the console is now saddening.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You should add parentheses around math expression:

```
(max-width: ($tablet - 1px))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change it to this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: ($tablet - 1px) {
```